# find with grep not returning results

Tags: grep, find

The first line returns dozens of finds.  The second line returns nothing.

```
sudo find /var/www/ . -type 'f' -name index.php | grep "php"           
sudo find /var/www/ . -type 'f' -name index.php | grep "require"
```

There are files called `index.php` that contain both text strings.  Why doesn't the second line seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be calling xargs before piping to grep.  What you have is grep searching the results of find, not the contents of the files that find has found.

```
sudo find /var/www/ . -type 'f' -name index.php | xargs grep "php"
```

If you do lots of searching like this, you may want to look at [ack](http://betterthangrep.com).  For instance, to search all the PHP files in /var/www for "require", you would use:

```
ack --php require /var/www
```